# Forward class declaration is interchangeable with the class keyword in the place of use?

Tags: c++

Are these two equivalent?

Code 1:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
    B fun1() const;
    B* m_b;
};

extern void myfun( const B& b );
```

Code 2:

```
class A {
public:
    class B fun1() const;
    class B* m_b;
};

extern void myfun( const class B& b );
```

Or is there some problematic points with use programming style presented in Code 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are different if you have an enclosing scope.

Case 1:

```
class B { };
namespace test {
    class B;  // declares test::B

    class A {
    public:
        B fun1() const; // refers to test::B
        B* m_b;         // also refers to test::B
    };

    class B { int x; };  // defines test::B
}
```

Case 2:

```
class B { };
namespace test {
    class A {
    public:
        class B fun1() const; // refers to ::B
        class B* m_b;         // also refers to ::B
    };

    class B { int x; };  // defines test::B
}
```

---

More details:

`class B;` is one of two things. It's either a redeclaration, or a forward declaration that introduces the name `B` into the current scope (§9.1 [class.name]/p2 of the standard).

`class B` itself is called an *elaborated-type-specifier*. When you use it to declare something, the compiler first looks up to see if a type called `B` is in scope (§3.4.4 [basic.lookup.elab]/p2, §9.1 [class.name]/p3 note). If there is, then the *elaborated-type-specifier* is taken to refer to that.

If not, then it will also declare a new name. The difference with a forward declaration is in the scope in which this new name is declared. If used to specify the return type or parameter type of a function of namespace scope, it's taken to declare the name in the namespace that contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the name is declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration (§3.3.2 [basic.scope.pdecl]/p7). Note that this will never declares the name in class scope; in other words, it will never declare a nested class.

Why use forward declarations instead of the alternative? First, it can declare the name in any scope, not just block and namespace scope. Second, forward declarations are less fragile. Note that in the second case if I move the definition of `test::B` before `test::A` then suddenly the `class B`s in `test::A` are referring to `test::B` rather than `::B`. Third, do you really want to have to remember an entire paragraph of rules about which scope a declared name is put in?